# How I manually fix my grass mesh normals so all textures are visible?

Tags: texturing, normals

have been exporting models from blender to the hammer editor recently and have come across a problem with this particular grass model:

[image]

Some of the grass wasn't visible in the editor I was exporting it to and I looked in the face orientation view to find that most of the inside of the model was red, meaning it wouldn't be visible once exported.

[image]

I then tried to recalculate my normals outside in edit mode. This was the fix I did before when I had texturing problems, but with this mesh, little to no change is seen when I do it.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

I also tried recalculating inside but it gave me the same problem with the texture but now on the inside instead:

[image]

I asked in a chat about this and people said I need manually change my normals. How would I do this so both sides are visible? When I select a face, it selects both sides i.e the red and blue side. Will this be a problem when I'm changing them?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by selecting a face selects both. For example, any one of the small triangles on the very left is a face (which is blue because it is front facing). Are saying you couldn't select it and flip it's (and only it's) normal if you wanted?

Comment: Yes sort of. If I selected that blue face on the left of the last photo, because the mesh has no thickness, I am also selecting the red face on the other side. My worry with that was if I flipped that normal on the red side it would also flip it on the blue. I've just tried it out and it does do this

Comment: Normals and face direction are one sided. With something "two dimensional" like a plane, face direction is determined by normal direction - ie, all red faces are facing away and have their normals facing away. Select all of the red faces, and select `mesh > normals > flip`.

Comment: I've Done that. It gave me the same results as when I tried to recalculate inside. All red faces have gone blue and all blue faces have gone red.

Comment: Weird. Any chance you could upload a .blend? I might have better luck solving it if I saw what was going on.

Comment: Yeah can do. Can you upload files to the post you've made or does it have to be on my profile or something?

Comment: Go here - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ Upload the file, paste the URL of this question - they will give you a link. Edit this question, and paste in the link they give you.

Comment: I've modified the post to include the link.

Comment: Ok. Hang on, i'm just thinking about this for a second. Is your end goal that you be able to look at from any angle and only see one color (red or blue)?

Comment: Yes my end goal is for all of the model to be blue so when I export it to the hammer editor all of it is visible. (not just the inside or outside)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately things don't work that way. Think of a plane as a playing card - only one side has numbers, and no matter how much you tear, twist or turn it, it will always stay that way. However, just because a face is pointing one way, doesn't mean it can't be double sided (visible from both sides). If you can't see the whole thing, it's likely the result of backface-culling on behalf of the hammer editor (that's trimming away the faces it considers "back facing"). See if you can turn it off for this object.

Comment: See here - https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/$nocull

Comment: hmmm.. well thank you anyway. It doesn't appear you can turn it off for objects in particular which is a shame. I have an Idea of a fix by creating two of the same meshes. have one recalculated inside and one recalculated out and have them exactly the same position. After that joining them and exporting them as one. If that works, I will come back and answer my own question with this solution.

Comment: ohh nevermind then i'll give it a go.

Comment: After testing around I found that yes, using "$nocull 1" in my .vmt texture file completely removes the culling of the textures in the hammer editor. We have a working fix!

Comment: Awesome. Glad you got it working.